# Extract directory link from file link

Tags: r

Is it possible to get the directory from a link like these in R?

```
"/a/home/b/c.csv"
```

I am trying to extract `"/a/home/b"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, I've used `strsplit` on `.Platform$path.sep`.  But it turns out the built-in `dirname` exists!

```
> path = "/a/home/b/c.csv"
> dirname(path)
[1] "/a/home/b"
```

Comment: I was trying dir all these while:). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @itthrill `dir` = `list.files`.